# Changing values when transforming dataframe to list

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

I have an issue that I have been working on for some time now but cannot understand.

I am working on a data analysis project in Python. I have this dataset, which contains coordinate points x and y. I store the dataset in a panda `DataFrame`, called df. The dataset contains 400 rows, with each 2 columns containing the x and y coordinate, which are `float64` objects.

For my calculations, I need to transform this `DataFrame` into a `list`, lets call it df_list. I do this using the `df.values.tolist()` command.

I also need to transform the identical `dataframe` into a `numpy array`, lets call this df_numpy. I do this using the `df.to_numpy()` command.

Now, the issue I have is that some values do not get translated correctly into the `list`. The weird thing is that it is always one coordinate entry that is wrong, but not always the same.

Let me explain by giving some output values:

```
print(df.loc[0])
print(df.loc[1])
print(df.loc[2])
print(df.loc[3])
print(df.loc[4])
```

> X 1.000000
>
> Y 0.561865
>
> Name: 0, dtype: float64
>
> X 0.351548
>
> Y 0.002068
>
> Name: 1, dtype: float64
>
> X 0.523878
>
> Y 0.337961
>
> Name: 2, dtype: float64
>
> X 0.948091
>
> Y 0.456298
>
> Name: 3, dtype: float64
>
> X 0.608648
>
> Y 0.806752
>
> Name: 4, dtype: float64

```
print(df_numpy[0])

print(df_numpy[1])

print(df_numpy[2])

print(df_numpy[3])

print(df_numpy[4])
```

> [1.         0.56186462]
>
> [0.35154843 0.00206845]
>
> [0.52387755 0.33796057]
>
> [0.94809129 0.45629823]
>
> [0.60864801 0.80675194]

```
print(df_list[0])

print(df_list[1])

print(df_list[2])

print(df_list[3])

print(df_list[4])
```

> [1.0, 0.5618646171659081]
>
> [0.3515484263307057, 0.0020684547262851357]
>
> [0.5238775486787602, 0.3379605736871545]
>
> [1.1245393310467733, 0.6538012024565103]
>
> [0.6086480098218077, 0.8067519389187792]

As you can see, the number at location 3 in the `list` differs from the numbers in the `DataFrame` and the `numpy array`.

Is there some explanation why this could happen?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see any other reason to behave differently. Only concern is when pandas documentation is suggesting not to df.values, they might be aware of some performance issue. I will definitely research on that. I don't know the need of both np array and the list. But if you need both, then you can use df.to_numpy for np array and df.to_numpy().tolist() for the list.

Answer (score 0):

**Deprecate your usage of pandas.DataFrame.values!**

If you visit the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values) for .values, you will see a big red warning that says:

**Warning: We recommend using DataFrame.to_numpy() instead.**